# Override '=' as a string in shell script with arguments

Tags: shell

I am trying to call a shell script along with arguments something like this:

```
sh test.sh -arg1="ab" -arg2="cd" -arg3="ef=gh"
```

Script code is like:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
  do
          key=${1%=*}
              case $key in
                          "-arg1") arg1=${1#$key=} ;;
                          "-arg2") arg2=${1#$key=} ;;
                          "-arg3") arg3=${1#$key=} ;;
                          esac
                                          shift;
                                      done

  echo "arg1 is $arg1 arg2 is $arg2 and arg3 is $arg3"
```

it is displaying correct arg1 and arg2 but arg3 is showing to be empty. I think this is because of the '='
 sign inside arg3. Any help regarding how could i override it.

Thanks

Comment: Ankur Lathi is right, of course, but if you need to use the -arg1= syntax, I wonder whether the bash function getops, or the separate command getopt, would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace the line of code:
 `key=${1%=*}` 
with this one:
 `key=${1%%=*}`

Comment: +1.  Using `${1%%=*}` would return the longest trailing match of `=*`.

Comment: Hi,This didnt' worked. I replaced "-arg3") arg3=${1#$key=} ;; with "-arg3") arg3=${1%%$key=} ;; still didn't worked.

Comment: Please let me know if i am doing any error since i am a naive so i might be doing this wrong i am using zsh

Comment: Hi , It worked. Thanks a lot. I did the correction at wrong place. Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

You can access command line arguments directly by using:

```
$0 -- Name of File
$1 -- 1st Argument
$2 -- 2nd Argument
$3 -- 3rd Argument
.
.
.
```

**test.sh**

```
echo "arg1 is $1 arg2 is $2 and arg3 is $3"
```

**Command to run**

```
sh test.sh "ab" "cd" "ef=gh"
```

**Output**

```
arg1 is ab arg2 is cd and arg3 is ef=gh
```

Comment: the demand of the script is something like that the arguments passed in the script should be position independent.. for instance if a run sh test.sh "ab" "cd" "ef=gh" or sh test.sh "ef=gh" "cd" "ab" arg1 should always take ab, arg2 cd and arg3 ef=gh

Answer (score 0):

```
-arg3="ef=gh"
```

You will need to escape the = character

```
-arg3="ef\=gh"
```

Comment: Try escaping the escape sign as well  `-arg3="ef\\=gh"`